Simple Way of Iterating over Indexes of Bash Special Array $@
When I create an array in bash, let's say,
ARR=(apple banana blueberry)

I can easily iterate over the indexes of $ARR by using ${!ARR[@]} to get the indexes, as in:
for i in ${!ARR[@]}; do
   echo "[$i]=${ARR[$i]}"
done

How do I do that to iterate over ${@}?
I first tried to get some "equivalence" with:
__fn(){ 
    for i in ${!@}; do
        echo "\[$i\]=${@\[$i\]}";
    done;
}

But I got "Bad Substitution" errors.
As a "workaround" I did a copy of the array with ARRAY=( "${@}" ), but I'm looking for a more elegant way of doing that.
PS: Just to clarify, since it's been pointed that this question is similar to another: as you can see in the body of my question, it's not about how to access the nth element of an array or anything like that. I would like to iterate over indexes of ${@}.

If you need the positions, iterate until $# which is the number of arguments. If you only need the arguments, just use for i; do.

$@ has special behaviour and isn't a bash array. for example: https://github.com/gitGNU/gnu_bash/blob/bc007799f0e1362100375bb95d952d28de4c62fb/subst.c#L9494

This question is similar to: How to get the nth positional argument in bash?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also see BASH scripting: n-th parameter of $@ when the index is a variable?.

@pjh it has some slight distant relation, but it's a totally different question! I am asking about how to iterate indexes, not how to access the n-th entry.

This question is similar to: Iterate over arguments in a bash script and make use of their numbers. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Indexed arrays are sparse and more like associative arrays restricted to positive integer keys than like $@.

@AbdulAzizBarkat it's somewhat different, or perhaps not, I'm giving some thought if it's not just semantics... I mean, I was mistakenly assuming ${@} was an array because of the syntax I was using. I was asking how to iterate what I thought to be an special array. But now I realized ${@} isn't an array, so, I'm not sure.

Are you sure you are clear on the difference between indexed arrays (e.g. plain old arrays, e.g. declare -a array) and associative arrays (e.g. declare -A array)? I ask because you attempt to iterate with ${!ARR[@]} which is how your return the keys for an associative array. If you are clear on the difference, that's fine, it just wasn't clear from the question. If not, that could be the source of some of your confusion.


How do I do that to iterate over ${@}?

Usually eat arguments while iterating, for example when parsing options after getopt or getopts.
while (($#)); do
   echo "$1"
   shift
done

If you want to loop non-destructively and have an index, I would:
for ((i=1; i<=$#; ++i)); do
   echo "[$i]=${!i}"
done

If you are comfortable with arrays, just use an array:
arr=("$@")


But I got "Bad Substitution" errors.

There is no such thing as ${@[$i]}. The ${!@} tries to do indirect expansion of the result of $@ and fails.

I did a copy of the array with ARRAY=${@}

ARRAY here is not assigned to be an array. ARRAY=${@} is a normal assignment, not an array.

Thanks a lot for the answer! In the end I poorly reported how I assigned the ARRAY, I actually used ( "${@}" ) but wrote in a hurry. The array suggestion is pretty similar to that. I edited right now. Anyway, I liked your answer, but I'll still wait to see if something comes up to solve it iterating over indexes of ${@} specifically, without shift or incrementing the index, the way I would iterate over ${arr[@]} but without the need to copy the array. Or it isn't possible at all and I'm expecting too much?

for i in $(seq $#) is the usual POSIX compatible way.

$@ isn't an array, and so doesn't have indices. It is, however, composed of the positional parameters 1 through $#.

@KamilCuk seq itself is not specified by POSIX, though, although the loop syntax is POSIX-compliant.

@chepner thanks for clarifying. I really thought ${@} was an array for some reason, and it was my fundamental mistake here.

@Ágatha $@ (which itself is just a variant of $*) predates arrays in shell.
